# Document List Indexed Column goes missing

Tags: 2007, column

We are currently trying to troubleshoot a problem in Sharepoint 2007 where a custom column loses the "indexed column" setting.  We are trying to track this down, but has been mostly a reactive approach.

We have not found any timer jobs that run when we believe this to be removed.
We have not seen any scheduled tasks that run at or near the same time as we believe the index to be removed.

Any other ideas of where to look would be appreciated.

NEW INFORMATION

Our team has been digging deeper.  It would seem that the original content type definition is being re-applied and causing the index to be turned off.  Can someone provide any ideas for triggers that would cause the content type definition to be re-applied to a list (Site Collection Documents) that may not be a Timer Job?

Comment: What column are you losing the index on?

Comment: Sorry this has taken so long to reply...I never saw a notification that there was a response.  The field is a custom document ID field [GUID].  I have noticed with some monitoring scripts that this happens during a code deployment.